# Perform action after user contol on tab page is visible

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my MVVM app I have a tab control with a couple of tabs.  Whenever a tab is selected, a user control on that tab page gets loaded, and in that user control's constructor, a call is made that takes a little time to complete.

I want to change it so that the call is made after the user control is loaded and visible to the user.  I tried the IsVisibleChanged event, but it returns Visible=true before I actually see the control, almost once I click the tab.

Is there a way I can make the call only after the control is done loading and visible on the screen to the user?

**Update:**
Some more info The call right now is an async call. The issue seems to be that after the asycn call is done, the dataSource of a grid on the user control is updated and that takes a second or so. As a result, it looks like it takes a second or so to switch tabs, when what really happening is the grid being loaded with some data. That's why I was looking for a way to start the request which triggers the eventual data load only after the tab switch is completed and the user control is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an async call to your time consuming method/function. With .NET 4 and TPL this is easily accomplished using the `Task` class...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(MyLittleTimeFunction);
```

or:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => serviceAgent.MyFunc(myParam)).
    ContinueWith(t => MyOtherFunc(myOtherParam));
```

Comment: Thanks Dean.  The call right now is an async call.  The issue seems to be that after the asycn call is done, the dataSource of a gird on the user control is updated and that takes a second or so.  As a result, it looks like it takes a second or so to switch tabs, when what really happening is the grid being loaded with some data.  That's why I was looking for a way to start the request which triggers the eventual data load only after the tab switch is completed and the user control is visible.  I updated my question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Loaded event (Occurs when a FrameworkElement has been constructed and added to the object tree.) of a FrameWorkElement (which all WPF controls are derived from...so your usercontrol as well ;)

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I would think this is a good place to use an event.  The [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602714.aspx) class already provides a `Loaded` event.  Both the `Window` class and the [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx) user control inherit from it, so you can use this event. All you have to do is move the call to this event.  For a simple example, see the MSDN [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event page.

**EDIT** @YoupTube is correct, it's better to overload the user control event, not the window event, since you can put more user controls in one page.

Comment: -1 Don't use it on the window but on the usercontrol itself. That's what he asks for. And is better OOP design ;)